# How to write multitime NetCDF raster with rasterio and netCDF4?

Tags: python, netcdf, rasterio

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling
from netCDF4 import Dataset

mask=rasterio.open(path1)
dst_crs='EPSG:4326'
with rasterio.open(path2) as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, mask.width, mask.height, *mask.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
        })

    dst=Dataset(pathdst, "w", format="NETCDF4")
    for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
        reproject(
            source=rasterio.band(src, i),
            destination=dst.band(i),
            src_transform=src.transform,
            src_crs=src.crs,
            dst_transform=transform,
            dst_crs=dst_crs,
            resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

results in an error

> AttributeError: NetCDF: Attribute not found

What is the right way to make a multiband cycle here? The best solution would be writing reprojected bands (each one is a time) with transform parameters from mask (not a multiband file) from src to dst. I believe I should create a time dimension for dst.

Full error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-2d687936926e> in <module>
     21         reproject(
     22             source=rasterio.band(src, i),
---> 23             destination=dst.band(i),
     24             src_transform=src.transform,
     25             src_crs=src.crs,

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__getattr__()

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.getncattr()

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._get_att()

netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success()
```

By the way. The file appears in the destination folder (96B).

Comment: I wonder if rioxarray might help? https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject.html. Xarray has a to_netcdf method: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf.html

Comment: Yeah, it has this method, but it is nowhere written how to tell him the src information. Now I am facing the same problem with to_netcdf